# Referencing superview inside of view code class file

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, subview, addsubview

I'm currently trying to learn constraints and styling programmatically in `Swift`. I'm also trying to maintain clean and modularized code by splitting up code that relates to "styling".

I simply have my `LoginViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginView: LoginView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loginView = LoginView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)

        // AutoLayout
        loginView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsets.zero, excludingEdge: .bottom)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

}
```

Then my `LoginView`:

```
import UIKit

class LoginView: UIView {
    var shouldSetupConstraints = true

    var headerContainerView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Header Container View
        headerContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        headerContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.42, green:0.56, blue:0.14, alpha:1.0) // #6B8E23
        headerContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(headerContainerView)

        headerContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.topAnchor)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if(shouldSetupConstraints) {
            // AutoLayout constraints
            shouldSetupConstraints = false
        }
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Where I am getting stuck is with just simply trying to add this `headerContainerView` to the top of my `superview`. I want to be able to add it so it pins itself to the top, left and right of the `superview` and only 1/3 of the `superview's` height. I continue to try and reference the `superview` with no success and I cannot find a solution that helps me understand on the internet. Any suggestions on how I can complete this?

Thank you for taking the time for those that respond.

**NOTE**: I did start out using `PureLayout` which is really nice. However, I am an individual that likes to understand what is going on behind the scenes or at least how to write the code at its base level. You can see that I am using a `PureLayout` function in my `LoginViewController`, but I am looking to change that. I would prefer a solution that doesn't add a third party library.

Comment: Try to use SnapKit, it is more flexible.

Comment: Is there any reason to do layout in two places? I see the edges are done at the VC level and the top anchor is done inside `LoginView`. I would encourage you two use the following guidelines: The auto-layout code in a view can only reference itself or its descendant (never the superview). In this case, put all the layout code inside the VC

Comment: Also I don't see any code related to the height of the view.

Comment: Are you suggesting this is a bad architecture for building an iOS app? I just see a lot of talk in regards to MVC, but in iOS it appears it is really just MV because all the code goes into the `VC`. This resulting in you having a HUGE VC. Shouldn't the VC be utilized for functionality rather than code that effects the view of your app? That is why I'm trying to approach this from a split scenario. I feel its slightly cleaner. But I'm new and thankful for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `self` in the custom `UIView` class is the parent view of `headerContainerView` so , You can add this , Also I recommend to learn constraints first without 3rd party libraries to fully understand the concept as you will learn a lot from seeing conflicts and other things ,  once done , shift to libraries

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    // Header Container View
    headerContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    headerContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.42, green:0.56, blue:0.14, alpha:1.0) // #6B8E23
    headerContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.addSubview(headerContainerView)
    headerContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    headerContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    headerContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    headerContainerView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.heightAnchor, multiplier:1.0/3.0, constant: 0.0).active = true

}
```

// loginView layout

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loginView = LoginView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.view.addSubview(loginView)
    loginView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loginView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    loginView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    loginView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    loginView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Learning constraints is actually what I am trying to do. I was initially using `PureLayout` but wanted to learn constraints on my own. I have tried to implement your solution. However, when I `Build/Run` the application, the screen is black. Any ideas on why this is the case?

Comment: because  loginView = LoginView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        has zero frame

Comment: What would be the appropriate way of changing this? I attempted to add `LoginView(frame: CGReact(x:0,y:0,width:view.bounds.width,heigth:view.bounds.height)). But no success.

Comment: This helped tremendously. I'm seeing why and when I need to reference `self` and what `self` is in this instance. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
headerContainerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(self)
        make.leading.and.trailing.equalTo(self)
        make.height.equalTo(self.frame.height/3)
    }
```

With [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).

Answer (score 0):

With SnapKit, you can do the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loginView = LoginView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.view.addSubview(loginView)

    // AutoLayout
    loginView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left)
        make.right.equalTo(view.snp.right)
        make.top.equalTo(view.snp.top)
        make.height.equalTo(view.snp.height).multipliedBy(1/3)
    }
}
```